# how to ask Mathematica to start plot axis from $1$ in transposing a table?

Tags: plotting

In this code, how can I ask Mathematica to start $n$ axis from $1$, not $0$?

```
{data1, data2} = 
  Transpose[
   Table[{n^2 π^3, n π Cos[1/(n^2 π^3)]}, {n, 50}]];
a = ListLogPlot[{data1, data2}, PlotLegends -> {"f", "g"}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"n", ""}]
```

[image]

Comment: `TimeSeriesShift` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ListLogPlot[{data1, data2}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"f", "g"}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"n", ""}, 
 PlotRange -> {{1, All}, All}, 
 AxesOrigin -> {1, Automatic},  
 PlotRangeClipping -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: The option: AxesOrigin -> {1, 0} will do the trick

Comment: @charmin, please see the updated version.

Comment: Can you give the code where it does not work? Actually, the axis in the second plot is too large to say with certainty where it starts.

Comment: @DanielHuber Unfortunately, I can not send it for a personal reason, but the problem is solved by the edit "kglr" made.

Comment: @kglr Thank you very much. Now, it works for any function.